# Can a child workflow be executed asynchronously?

Tags: cadence-workflow

I'm trying to implement a perpetual workflow that commences with an activity that blocks until a message is delivered (namely, Redis' `BLPOP`). Once it completes, I want to start a new workflow asynchronously to do some sort of processing and return `ContinueAsNew` immediately.

I've tried to start the processing workflow using child workflows. What I've observed is that my parent workflow completes before the child is executed. Unless I process the returned future, but I don't really want to do that.

What would be the right way to do this? Is it possible to start a new regular workflow within a workflow? Would such action be implemented as part of the workflow or within an activity?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to wait for a child workflow to start before completing or *continuing as new* the parent.

If you are using the [Go Cadence Client](https://github.com/uber-go/cadence-client) the `workflow.ExecuteChildWorkflow` returns a [ChildWorkflowFuture](https://github.com/uber-go/cadence-client/blob/27edec85304b9da2f312cbfbbc2f27251068c2c5/workflow/workflow.go#L33:2) which extends a `Future` that returns the child workflow result. It also has [GetChildWorkflowExectution](https://github.com/uber-go/cadence-client/blob/27edec85304b9da2f312cbfbbc2f27251068c2c5/internal/workflow.go#L127) method that returns a `Future` that becomes ready as soon as the child is started. So to wait for a child workflow to start the following code can be used:

```
f := workflow.ExecuteChildWorklfow(ctx, childFunc)
var childWE WorkflowExecution
// The following line unblocks as soon as the child is started.
if err := f.GetChildWorkflowExecution().Get(&childWE); err != nil {
   return err
}
```

Child workflow has started with Workflow ID found in `childWE.ID` and Run ID in `childWE.RunID`

The Java equivalent is:

```
 ChildType child = Workflow.newChildWorkflowStub(ChildType.class);
 // result promise becomes ready when the child completes
 Promise<String> result = Async.function(child::executeMethod);
 // childWE promise becomes ready as soon as the child is started
 Promise<WorkflowExecution> childWE = Workflow.getWorkflowExecution(child);
```

Comment: Thanks, working like a charm! Minor observation: `childWE` should use the exported type `workflow.Execution` if I understood correctly.